# how to convert to upper case an array with plain ECMAscript5 just using while loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-5, uppercase

I have to do this simple exercise but I am really struggling a lot with it. I have to convert all the names to uppercase and pass it to the empty array, using only *while* loop(s), and I can't use any method, just plain javascript 5:

```
var names = ['rob', 'dwayne', 'james', 'larry', 'steve'];

var UpperCase = [];
```

I tried with an object like this (there are still some mistakes, it's just an idea):

```
var change = {
  "mary":"MARY",
  "john":"JOHN",
  "james":"JAMES",
  "anna":"ANNA",
  "jack":"JACK",
  "jeremy":"JEREMY",
  "susanne":"SUSANNE",
  "caroline":"CAROLINE",
  "heidi":"HEIDI"
}
for(var key in change) {
  var obj = change[key];

  for (var prop in obj) {
  var value = obj[prop];
}
}

while(names[i]===change.key) {
  for(var i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
  UpperCase = change.value[i];
} }
```

I hope somebody can help me with this one.

Thanks!

Comment: `I can't use any method`...like??????????

Comment: `toUpperCase` is plain javascript

Comment: It's basically impossible to answer this because you haven't clearly conveyed what are the limitations of this exercise. I assume the instructions are written down somewhere. Can you share them with us instead of giving us a watered-down version of them?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp
Here is a link that will open up some new worlds for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Instead of using toUppercase():**

Check if a character is uppercase or lowercase with this

```
str[i].charCodeAt(0) > 96
```

[charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)

[fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

**Using just while**

```
var i = 0;
while (i < str.length) ...
```

**Not using push function for array**

```
 UPPERCASE[UPPERCASE.length] = uppercase(names[i]);
```

I hope this function helps you

```
function uppercase(str) {
  var i = 0;
  var output = "";
  while (i < str.length) {
    var x =
      (str[i].charCodeAt(0) > 96)
        ? String.fromCharCode(str[i].charCodeAt(0) - 32)
        : String.fromCharCode(str[i].charCodeAt(0));
    output += x;
    i++;
  }
  return output;
}
```

Example:

```js
function uppercase(str) {
  var i = 0;
  var output = "";
  while (i < str.length) {
    var x =
      (str[i].charCodeAt(0) > 96) ?
      String.fromCharCode(str[i].charCodeAt(0) - 32) :
      String.fromCharCode(str[i].charCodeAt(0));
    output += x;
    i++;
  }
  return output;
}
var UPPERCASE = [];
var names = ["rOb", "dwayne", "james", "larry", "steve"];

var i = 0;

while (i < names.length) {
  UPPERCASE[UPPERCASE.length] = uppercase(names[i]);
  i++;
}

console.log(UPPERCASE);
```

---

**Update**

Answer without function and linear condition

```js
var UPPERCASE = [];
var names = ["rOb", "dwayne", "james", "larry", "steve"];

var i = 0;

while (i < names.length) {
  var j = 0,
    output = "",
    str = names[i];
  while (j < str.length) {
    var x;
    if (str[j].charCodeAt(0) > 96) {
      x = String.fromCharCode(str[j].charCodeAt(0) - 32);
    } else {
      x = String.fromCharCode(str[j].charCodeAt(0));
    }
    output += x;
    j++;
  }
  UPPERCASE[UPPERCASE.length] = output;
  i++;
}

console.log(UPPERCASE);
```

Comment: That was a good one mate! could you be able to do it maybe without creating a function?
As for the "?" and  the ":" are they like an if statement? I didn't know them yet

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an increment (i) so your while loop knows when to stop. It's a better case for a for loop but a while loop works as well.

```
var names = ['rob', 'dwayne', 'james', 'larry', 'steve']
var i = 0
var result = []

while (i < names.length) {
  result.push(names[i].toUpperCase())
  i++ 
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted something without using methods like .toUpperCase and .push

Answer (score 0):

you should use handler function in map:

```
var names = ['rob', 'dwayne', 'james', 'larry', 'steve'];
var UpperCase = names.map(function(x){ return x.toUpperCase() });
```

Comment: Including a link because I don't know if OP knows very much about `map`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: The exercise is supposed to be avoiding using any helper or function, just the simplest javascript possible you can, using while. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Improving a bit on @andrewgi's answer:

```
var names = ['rob', 'dwayne', 'james', 'larry', 'steve']
var i = 0
var result = []

while (i < names.length) {
  result.push(names[i].toUpperCase())
  i++ 
}

console.log(result)
```

I removed the `+1` after the `names.length` check and spelled `toUpperCase` with correct camel-case.

Comment: i did that in an edit before you posted yours. Yours is an exact replica of mine.

Comment: I must have made my answer while you were editing. I think the downvote is a little harsh. Sorry for upsetting you.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted something without using methods like .toUpperCase and .push